# PHP drop browser connection without using Content-Length

Tags: php, connection, content-length

I have a huge chunk of data that is sent to the browser via PHP. If I buffer and send it all at once I get memory issues, so I've been calling flush() and ob_flush() periodically throughout the output process.

Now I want the script to finish the output, close the connection, and run some background processes, but it seems the only way to do this is if I send the browser a header("Content-Length") beforehand (such as the method listed [here](https://www.zulius.com/how-to/close-browser-connection-continue-execution/)). The data is dynamically generated, so I can't know the content length without going through it once already, which is slow and expensive.

Is there a workaround or another way to close the browser connection without knowing how much data in total is being sent?

Edit: Problem solved. For anyone else who may want a solution to this without php-fpm like Zane suggested, I put the processing code after the browser output into a separate script. By calling the new script from the main one with cURL and have it immediately time out, the browser no longer waits for the secondary script to finish processing before terminating the connection. The secondary script needs to have ignore_user_abort() set to true though. Described [here](http://davenewson.com/posts/2012/methods-for-asynchronous-processes-in-php-5-4.html).

Comment: try this function `fastcgi_finish_request`, If you are using php-fpm.look [php-manual-fastcgi_finish_request](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php)

Comment: @Zane - This looks like exactly what I need! I'll try it out, thanks!

Comment: So it seems I can't really use this solution because I don't have the rights to the server to install php-fpm. Thanks anyways.